# Data binding a gridview using ObjectDataSource without Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, objectdatasource

I have 1000 of records to display in the grid view so I am using ObjectDataSource to do binding to the grid view.

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsProducts" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetProducts"
                TypeName="ProductsList" EnablePaging="True"  MaximumRowsParameterName="PageSize"
                SelectCountMethod="GetRowsCount" StartRowIndexParameterName="StartRow"></asp:ObjectDataSource> 

                    <asp:GridView ID="UserTable" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="odsProducts"
                        SelectedIndex="0" DataKeyNames="UserID" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" BorderStyle="Groove"
                        OnRowDataBound="UserTable_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
```

In the Data access layer I have a class`[Dataserver]` which does the open and close connection, I have a method called executeNonQuery method which is used to retrieve data from the DB.

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType commandType, string sql, MySqlParameter[] commandParameters)
{
   ...
   return rowsAffected;
}
```

So in my Getdata method of the OjectdataSource

```
 private DataView GetData(int StartRow, int PageSize)
{
  DataServer server = new DataServer();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  int newOrgID = 60;
    string userQuery = "Select tbl_User.UserID, tbl_User.FirstName, tbl_User.LastName, tbl_User.Email, tbl_User.PhoneNumber, tbl_User.CreatedBy, tbl_Organisation.OrganisationName from tbl_user WHERE Organisationid=@OrganisationID order by tbl_user.LastName asc";
    MySqlParameter[] para = new MySqlParameter[1];
    para[0] = new MySqlParameter("@OrganisationID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
    para[0].Value = newOrgID ;
    dt = server.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.Text, userQuery, para);
}
```

All the example in the web are with stored procedure can some one help me in doing this. The error I get here is I am not able to bind the grid view, cannot convert dataset into datable. So How can I use datatable to do the binding to the gridview

Answer (score 0):

Just change the signature of your `SelectMethod` from

```
private DataView GetData(int StartRow, int PageSize)
```

to

```
public DataTable GetProducts(MyNewParameter,StartRow,PageSize)
```

and return `dt` at the end of the method.

Good example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PagingWithODS.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use datatable to do the binding to the gridview

This example shows how you can bind to a GridView using a DataTable as your datasource:

```
MySqlCommand sm = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", database_connection);
MySqlDataAdapter sa = new MySqlDataAdapter(sm);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sa.Fill(dt); // store query results in dt

gv.DataSource = dt;
gv.DataBind();
```

This also illustrates how to execute a select query without using stored procedures or ObjectDataSource.

If you're using `System.Data.SqlClient` rather than `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`, rename the classes to `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter`.